# regex capturing inside a macro definition (SAS 9.4)

Tags: regex, sas

Here is a paraphrased version of my code:

```
options nofmterr symbolgen;

%macro data_checks(dset,newset);

    %if &newset=  %then
        %let newset = new;

    proc contents data=&dset out=work.&newset noprint;
    run;

    %local re yr;
    %let re = %sysfunc(prxparse('/_y(\d\d?)$/'));
    %let yr = %sysfunc(prxposn(&re, 1, &dset));

    %put &yr;
%mend data_checks

%data_checks(owners.ownersclean_y10, new_dataset);
```

As far as I can tell, the re string I have is fine.  SYMBOLGEN output in the log is telling me that `&re` is what appears to be a random integer between 1 and 10 each time I run it and `&yr` appears to resolve to an empty string each time.

What am I doing wrong?  `&yr` is supposed to resolve to `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems here:

- You must use PRXMATCH before PRXPOSN (or a few other match-making functions).  See the [documentation for PRXPOSN](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002601903.htm).
- You should not use `'` in the expression.

This works:

```
options nofmterr symbolgen;

%macro data_checks(dset,newset);

    %if &newset=  %then
        %let newset = new;

    %local re yr;
    %let re = %sysfunc(prxparse(/_y(\d\d?)$/));
    %let rc = %sysfunc(prxmatch(&re,&dset));
    %let yr = %sysfunc(prxposn(&re, 1, &dset));

    %put &=yr;
%mend data_checks;

%data_checks(owners.ownersclean_y10, new_dataset);
```

Comment: Do you have documentation for that first statement?  [this link](http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2010/TT/TT10.pdf) seems to use `prxposn` in `%sysfunc`.  Also, `prxposn` doesn't appear in [this list](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1o13d7wb2zfcnn19s5ssl2zdxvi.htm).  Could the problem perhaps be that the value stored in `&re` got truncated?

Comment: Hmm, that article explains nearly the exact opposite of what I'd thought.  But I also wouldn't ever do it this way - I would always use a datastep or an FCMP - so I am probably wrong.

Comment: Yep- entirely backwards!  Learn something new every day.

Comment: That article is calling `prxmatch` before calling `prxposn`.